# how many levels of master-detail relationship in salesforce object (multilevel relationship)

Tags: salesforce, master-detail

> How many Levels of master-Detail relationships can be created on salesforce object?
>   Just like multi-level inheritance in OOPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page says you can have up to 3 custom detail levels:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_considerations.htm

I'd be careful of having more than one level of detail objects.  Remember that the child (and grandchild records) are also deleted when the parent (master) record is deleted.  By default, it's not possible to re-parent child records.  This is a feature that must be enabled for your Salesforce instance

Also, you can't directly do a summary roll-up for grandchild records. The child record will first need a roll-up for the grandchild.